# Boost asio async UDP socket has high latency

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, latency

I'm having difficulty with latency when running an async asio udp socket. I don't have the same problems with an identical application that uses synchronous udp. I'm communicating with a physical device which permits a maximum 5ms latency for each UDP packet, and I'm currently getting a latency of 8ms with a std dev of 0.065ms which is surprisingly precise.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.10.4 with Xcode 6.3.2 (6D2105).

Here are some of the key details about this problem:

**Sync UDP test program**

- works, staying under 5ms latency 100% of the time for over an hour
- Code

  - main file [KukaFRIClientDataTest.cpp](https://github.com/ahundt/grl/blob/7460e5c1b1569f1de22b8431609fc6958c18a546/test/KukaFRIClientDataTest.cpp)
  - UDP socket communication class [KukaFriClientData.hpp](https://github.com/ahundt/grl/blob/7460e5c1b1569f1de22b8431609fc6958c18a546/include/grl/KukaFriClientData.hpp)
- Key lines

  - calls [`socket.receive_from()`](https://github.com/ahundt/grl/blob/7460e5c1b1569f1de22b8431609fc6958c18a546/include/grl/KukaFriClientData.hpp#L161) then [`socket.send()`](https://github.com/ahundt/grl/blob/7460e5c1b1569f1de22b8431609fc6958c18a546/include/grl/KukaFriClientData.hpp#L175) at the lowest level.

**Async UDP test program**

- high latency bug, 8ms w/ 0.065 ms std dev
- Code

  - main file [KukaFRITest.cpp](https://github.com/ahundt/grl/blob/7460e5c1b1569f1de22b8431609fc6958c18a546/test/KukaFRITest.cpp)
  - High level wrapper class [KukaFRIThreadSeparator.hpp](https://github.com/ahundt/grl/blob/7460e5c1b1569f1de22b8431609fc6958c18a546/include/grl/KukaFRIThreadSeparator.hpp)
  - Low level wrapper class [KukaFRI.hpp](https://github.com/ahundt/grl/blob/7460e5c1b1569f1de22b8431609fc6958c18a546/include/grl/KukaFRI.hpp).
- Key lines

  - calls [`socket_.async_receive_from()`](https://github.com/ahundt/grl/blob/7460e5c1b1569f1de22b8431609fc6958c18a546/include/grl/KukaFRI.hpp#L374) then that handler calls [`socket_.async_send_to()`](https://github.com/ahundt/grl/blob/7460e5c1b1569f1de22b8431609fc6958c18a546/include/grl/KukaFRI.hpp#L432), which calls the final callback with the results.

Does anyone have insight into why this latency issue may be occurring in the Async UDP version? Thanks.

Comment: In your `async_receive_from` case handler is allocated with slow standard `operator new`. Fast [custom allocation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_allocate.html) of handler would improve performance (though that maybe not the only issue). Also smaller test case is preferable - leave only necessary stuff, and it would be easier to test.

Comment: yeah, I realize that, but it is hard to make smaller. I could try just having the computer communicate with itself, but to communicate with the hardware device (a robot) certain requirements have to be met... I'm not sure new is the issue because times would vary more and I'd expect it to show up high on the profiler list. Someone on the boost mailing list indicated thread priority could be it and I need to set realtime priority, which would make sense if it yields itself to sleep for 8ms every time.

Comment: I've no idea what the cause is, but have an upvote anyway for providing numbers that show an alternative does not have the same issue.

Comment: Interestingly enabling realtime mode with `thread_policy_set()` didn't fix the problem, and actually increased the variation. I'm sure I could pick parameters that would reduce variation, but I don't think it would change or solve the 8ms problem. 
mean = 8.000 [ms], std = 0.176, max/min = 17.615/0.059; 6999 iter.

Comment: For what it is worth, I have not been able to duplicate the results with a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It may be worth considering writing your own mcve for the specific environment and seeing if the async performance will meet the requirements.  Also, Boost.Asio does have some [latency tests](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/tree/boost-1.58.0/test/latency) that may serve as reference material.

Comment: @TannerSansbury great suggestion, I will try it when I have free time. Thanks!